# Why is it undefined to derefrence a pointer to extern union?

Tags: c, pointers, unions, c89

I have the following code. Why its undefined to derefrence union pointers in the following way ?

```
extern union MyUn *P1;          
extern union MyUn *P2;

extern void myfunc(void)
{
      *P1 = *P2;                
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That has nothing to do with unions in particular, and it's not "undefined", either: It's simply a compiler error if you try to dereference a pointer to an incomplete type (for obvious reasons).

Comment: By simple compiler error you mean a constraint violation, don't you :)

Answer (score 7):

If you haven't also defined the union in this source file, the compiler doesn't know how much to copy.

What is the size of the union?

Comment: If the union isn't known at that point, won't `*P1` and `*P2` be incomplete types ? Thus the dereference itself is not OK.

Comment: Yes, the main problem with incomplete `struct` and `union` types is that they are of unknown size (and contain unknown members).